# Animate vertical sub menu with css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

We have menu and some of this menu has a sub-menu. i want to display sub-menu when come to display block with animation. specially height of sub-menu.
for example:

```
#menu ul.sub_menu {
    display             : none;
}

#menu li:hover ul.sub_menu {
    display             : block;
}
```

please see my code [jsfiddle.net/oa6ftrL8/](https://jsfiddle.net/oa6ftrL8/), thanks

Answer (score 3):

You cannot animate the `display` property. Go with `opacity: 0;` instead of `display: none;` and `opacity: 1;` instead of `display: block;`

Add some `max-height: 0;` and `max-height: fartoomanypx;` for the animation (because `height` cannot be animated to `auto`).

https://jsfiddle.net/oa6ftrL8/1/

You will have to start fiddling yourself to make it beautiful.